# Sum of values of two fields in Elasticsearch index as a single field using query

Tags: elasticsearch

ES index:

```
{
  "_index": "test1",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "0mRtoGgBnyB5Q6tBVGHK",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "spread": 0,
    "Class": "match",
    "price": 0.2,
    "qty": 3,
    "Id": 1
  }
  }
```

This is the document in my Elasticsearch index. I need to get the sum of price and qty for each document as result of the query to the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Script Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html#search-request-script-fields) which will return a script evaluation (based on different fields) for each hit

Try something like below:

```
GET test1/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "totalcost" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc['price'].value * doc['qty'].value"
            }
        },
        "sumpriceandqty" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc['price'].value + doc['qty'].value"                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: *Updated Index Name*

I tested it on local, it works, here's the output :

```
{
  "took": 67,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test1",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "_xEopmgBbjdm4NNpj-tl",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "sumpriceandqty": [
            3.2000000029802322
          ],
          "totalcost": [
            0.6000000089406967
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this it gives me the following error:{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Variable [price] is not defined."}

Comment: Well, that says it cant find the field. Make sure you are using the right index, correct field name and also the fielddata is not disabled

Comment: I checked the index name is right and field name too. I get the following error

Comment: "script":"doc[price].value + doc[qty].value","lang":"painless"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"table1","node":"n9syu_a5S4aVcgFEMoR6HA","reason":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"compile error","script_stack":["doc[price].value + doc[qty].v ...","    ^---- HERE"],"script":"doc[price].value + doc[qty].value","lang":"painless","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Variable [price] is not defined."}}}]},

Comment: Not sure if you copied and pasted the query, but make sure you do `GET test1/_search`. I tested and updated the result

Comment: @DishaKShetty You are not wrapping field name single quotes and thats the reason for the error. Please use `doc['price'].value + doc['qty'].value` instead of `doc[price].value + doc[qty].value`

Comment: I am using the single quotes I dont know why in the error it isnt showing but I am using it and also checked the index name

Comment: @DishaKShetty As I can see in the error `"shard":0,"index":"table1","node":"n9syu_a5S4aVcgFEMoR6HA",` the index you are querying on is `table1`